# Jquery change button value not working

Tags: jquery, html, dom, jquery-mobile

I've been struggling for hours and I cannot get the following code to work;

```
<li>
<img width="100px" height="100px" src="$profile_picture">
<p>Username: $username</p>
<p>UserID: $userid</p>
<p>Bio: $bio</p>
<p>Website: $website</p>
<input type="button" value="Block" data-role="button" id="myButton"/>
</li>
<li data-role="list-divider"></li>
```

I want to change the value of button to "blocked", this is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input[type='button']").toggle(function () {
    $(this).val("Block");
}, function () {
    $(this).val("Blocked");
});
</script>
```

I'm using the following version of jquery and jqm:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

Any idea why this isn't working properly? all help is very appreciated...TKS!

Comment: You're using a function that was removed from jQuery as of 1.9 (deprecated in 1.8): http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - I have no idea what you're talking about, but yes, the toggle event was removed. The toggle animation method still exists however. Read the link in my comment.

Comment: I think I had my eyes crossed. nevermind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `toggle()` function used that way was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in 1.9

```
$("#myButton").on('click', function(){
    $(this).val(function(i,val) {
        return val=='Block' ? 'Blocked' : 'Block';
    });
});
```

And you should load jQuery before mobile:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

And remember the document ready function, or add the code at the bottom.

Comment: Always typing faster... +1

Comment: I've loaded jQuery before mobile, only pasted it wrong here, tks!

Comment: Note that you should be careful using `document.ready` to run your code as jQuery Mobile uses an AJAX navigation model by default that relies more on `pageinit` (and etc): http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

Comment: @Jasper - That's a valid point, jQ Mobile uses the pageinit event.

Comment: @Tuga - Not sure why it does'nt work for you, it seems to work fine for me, here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/28Rw6/) ??

Answer (score 5):

The `toggle` function you are using is removed in jQuery version 1.9 (version deprecated: 1.8, removed: 1.9)

http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

You could achieve the same by implementing this on `click` handler and toggle the values.

**Why was it removed?** [version 1.9]

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed

> This is the "click an element to run the specified functions" signature of `.toggle()`. It should not be confused with the "change the visibility of an element" of `.toggle()` which is not deprecated. The former is being removed to reduce confusion and improve the potential for modularity in the library. The jQuery Migrate plugin can be used to restore the functionality.

**Why was it deprecated?** [version 1.8]

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11786

> Did you know we have two .toggles? The one we like performs .show or .hide as appropriate, and is documented at  http://api.jquery.com/toggle/. The other sets up round-robin .click handlers, and is documented at  http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/:
>
> The .toggle() method is provided for convenience. It is relatively straightforward to implement the same behavior by hand, and this can be necessary if the assumptions built into .toggle() prove limiting. For example, .toggle() is not guaranteed to work correctly if applied twice to the same element. Since .toggle() internally uses a click handler to do its work, we must unbind click to remove a behavior attached with .toggle(), so other click handlers can be caught in the crossfire. The implementation also calls .preventDefault() on the event, so links will not be followed and buttons will not be clicked if .toggle() has been called on the element.
>
> Let's put it out of our misery.

Comment: what was the problem so that it was removed?

Comment: It was too similar to the toggle() function that toggles visibility, among other things.

Comment: @Tuga If it helps any, I made a jQ Plugin to replace this functionality. Of course it's called [**toggleMethod**](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/pu8ZS/) and can easily be copied from that fiddle into a js file. Place link in head after jQuery link and you're good to go. use as easy as `$("element").toggleMethod(function(e) { /* DO WORK */ }, function(e) { /* DO WORK */ });`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what guys said, you can use another toggle in slightly different manner

```
 <input type="button" value="Block" data-role="button" class="myButton"/>
 <input type="button" value="Blocked" data-role="button" class="myButton" style="display:none;"/>
```

And

```
$(".myButton").on('click', function (){
    $('.myButton').toggle()
});
```